# How do I fix my SHA512 checksum mismatch error in electron?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

I am trying to add auto update support to my electrom-app using electron-updater(electron-builder version), and it has gotten to the point where it starts to download the update but the download progress just decreases and increases infinitely afterwards. After checking the logs, it says there is a sha512 checksum mismatch, and that it got an incorrect SHA512 value. I tried to solve it by checking some previous issues and trying applying those but they didn't work. I read that it might be because of my code signing techniques(I use my EV Code signing cert to code sign my app after I make the executable using a sign tool command). To try and solve this, I tried integrating it with electron builder using sign.js, but that did not work, since it would try to sign the .exe before it even existed. Additionally, I tried going into the latest.yml and manually changing the sha512 values of the update and the original software to match, but that didn't make a difference either. What can I do, and what exactly does this error mean?

Here is info about my project if that helps.
Error Code

```
Error in auto-updater. Error: sha512 checksum mismatch, expected <long_encrypted_value>, got <different_long_encrypted_value>
```

Electron-Builder Version: 22.9.1

Node Version: 16.7
Electron Version: 18.2.0
Electron Type (current, beta, nightly): Current
Electron Builder Version: 4.3.9
Target: Windows